# how to delete first rows if i have pairs of almost identical rows

Tags: database, sqlite

I have sqlite Table named 'SULP' and look like this:

```
name year month day hour min ro   
"SULP","12","7","7","0","0","2.41196"   *
"SULP","12","7","7","0","0","2.39269"
"SULP","12","7","7","0","1","2.41117"   *
"SULP","12","7","7","0","1","2.39198"
"SULP","12","7","7","0","2","2.41004"   *
"SULP","12","7","7","0","2","2.39117"
"SULP","12","7","7","0","3","2.40914"   *
"SULP","12","7","7","0","3","2.39043"
```

I wont to delete rows marked by *

I have tried

```
delete from SULP 
       where exists (select * from 'SULP' as t2 WHERE t2.year=year
       AND t2.month=month AND t2.day=day AND t2.hour=hour AND 
       t2.min=min and ro<>t2.ro order by rowid desc limit 1);
```

and

```
delete from 'SULP' 
      where exists (select * from 'SULP' as t2 WHERE t2.year=year 
      AND t2.month=month AND t2.day=day AND t2.hour=hour AND 
      t2.min=min AND rowid<t2.rowid);
```

but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
DELETE FROM SULP WHERE (
    SELECT MIN(ro) FROM SULP AS t2
    WHERE year  = SULP.year
      AND month = SULP.month
      AND day   = SULP.day
      AND hour  = SULP.hour
      AND min   = SULP.min
   ) <> ro;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want :

```
DELETE FROM SULP
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM SULP t2
GROUP BY name, year, month, hour, min
HAVING SULP.rowid = min(t2.rowid)  
)
```

See **[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a150f/27/2)**

Comment: I need to delet not row with max "ro" but first in two "copies". It may be min somwhere

Comment: Whis and previous post works in fiddle but dont work from command line and sqlite manager...it's strange  just freezing and have 100% cpu load

Comment: You wrote : "first in two "copies"." .... OK... but how you determine wich one is first?

Comment: I think it should be `HAVING SULP.rowid = min(t2.rowid)`  But still it freezing

Comment: "OK... but how you determine wich one is first?" Like I post upthere, I have a new day start from 0h0min and I have 2 such lines...delete first. I think by rowid

Comment: I changed it to `rowid`. Still working fine in fiddle...May be you can try to copy your table with an `INSERT` using `SULP.rowid = max(t2.rowid)` and replace it after...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the subquery, both `t2.year` and `year` refer to the column of the `t2` table.

You must use `SULP.year` to refer to the outer table:

```
DELETE FROM "SULP"
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM "SULP" AS t2
              WHERE t2.year  = SULP.year
                AND t2.month = SULP.month
                AND t2.day   = SULP.day
                AND t2.hour  = SULP.hour
                AND t2.min   = SULP.min
                AND t2.ro    < SULP.ro)
```

Comment: Thanks, but still first code delete all rows thet have a copy, and second code freze

Comment: This delete evrithing